# Collapsible panel - MVC3 - Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Whats the best approach to take if I want to include a Collapsible panel in a MVC3 web page. In a Non MVC3 page, it is as easy as to drag and drop an Ajax control from the tool kit. I want to get that same functionality in my MVC3 application.. Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: if you'll have several collapsible panels I'd recommend jquery.ui accordion (http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AJAX Toolkit is built for ASP.NET Web Forms, while it may work using ASP.NET MVC, it's not really recommended.

I'd go with a, in my opinion, cleaner solution - try the [jQuery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/).

I've used it in several MVC based sites, and hasn't let me down so far.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I used the code they have in the link you provided, but the accordion does not collapse panels. I just get static headers and contents. Am I missing something?